# Angularjs Inter directive communication (parent-child directives) with a named ctrl of the parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object), and numerous other examples, It seems that the best way to handle common functions and communication between directives is requiring a "parent" directive and then the controller of the parent directive is supposed to be available as another argument of the link function - something like: `(scope, element,attrs, ctrl)`.

as seen in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iVnMJgTGxOM3u0h0Rc9J?p=preview). this Ctrl doesn't really exist AFAIK. (the plunker isn't the real use case but simplfied.. ) So I guess I'm doing something wrong.  I'm currently using events with `emit`, `broadcast` and `on` methods to pass information between the directives and the Ctrl, but that doesn't seem to be very `angularish`.. So I guess I'm missing something obvious

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that my mistake was the functions on the controller are on `$scope` while they should have been attached to `this`. attaching to `this` allows the child directive scope to "know" about the ctrl methods . I updated the original plunker with the answer.